# bootstrap3 tooltip in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

im new to bootstrap3 and im trying to use tooltip in a form element:

```
<form>
<div class="form-control">
<input type="text" id="test"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Content">
</div>
</form>
```

then i use javascript to init tooltip

```
$("#test").tooltip();
```

it not work, google chorme thorw exception : " Object # has no method 'toLowerCase' "

but i removed the form tag, it works fine ??

how can i use tooltip in a form?

Comment: [**Works for me!**](http://jsfiddle.net/2CDTJ/). Maybe you are not calling the tooltip method on `document.ready`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works with the `<form>` tag. http://bootply.com/102983

[image]